# Accurev treats most of the source tree in workspace as external

Tags: external, workspace, accurev

I have this accurev issue where almost *ALL* source-controlled dirs under my workspace are shown as "external" eventhough they are not --accurev stat confirms the same externality. Accurev update has not solved the problem: just pulls down the entire source tree everytime, indicating that the existing file-structure is external to accurev. I have poked around accurev manauals but, have not seen anything specifics on what the problem(s) might be. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

In the past, when this has happened to me, deleting everything in the external view and repopulating the workspace fixed this problem.

I usually just delete from the GUI if possible. Then open a command prompt, browse to the root directory of the workspace in question and run:

```
accurev pop -R *
```

Answer (score 1):

You may have had an "accurev update" fail for some reason, which has left the workspace out of sync.  To find out if this was indeed the root cause, you can run "accurev show -fx wspaces" from a command prompt and compare the Target_trans and Trans values.  If they are different, you have an inconsistent workspace.

To resolve this, you can run "accurev update -9" which will force the update level to the appropriate transaction.  Subsequently you can delete all external files, as Josh indicated, and re-populate them.  The command for this would be "accurev pop -R ."

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but I just had this issue.

Updating my workspace with "Timestamp Optimization" unchecked resolved the problem.