# AccuRev: Some files from the backing stream aren't in my workspace and aren't Missing

Tags: accurev

3 files present in the backing stream in AccuRev aren't in my workspace after Updating it.

Some things I've tried:

- Checked the Missing search. They don't show, with or without timestamp optimization.
- Recursively populated the parent of the directories where the missing files are(n't). Got nothing.
- Manually copied them from another workspace under the same stream, where they do show. Those copies appeared as External in my workspace, so I deleted them.
- As per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7046595/accurev-treats-most-of-the-source-tree-in-workspace-as-external), did `accurev show -fx wspaces`. Target_trans for that workspace is the same as Trans.
- Ran `accurev update -9` anyway. AccuRev says everything's up to date, nothing to do.

Other possibly-relevant info:

- Two coworkers with workspaces off that same backing stream have the files I'm missing.
- All 3 "missing" files are in one of 2 directories that were renamed fairly recently.
- The stream hierarchy is shallow, only one parent between the backing stream and the root. However, that parent stream wasn't always there. It was recently inserted, and all changes from our prior release change paletted into it, so the issues list for the backing stream would reflect only changes since the prior release, not since the beginning of time. It has had that effect, with no other anomalies I'm aware of.

I could abandon this workspace and create a new one, but I'd rather not if I don't have to. Any further suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: I forgot to mention that also restarted AccuRev, then my whole machine, no change. But this morning I came into work, ran Update, the log of which didn't include getting those files, but now they're there. I can see them in my workspace in AccuRev, and in IntelliJ. All of which is great in that it unblocks me, but it's nothing like an actual explanation of what happened, or how to fix it if it does.

Comment: Don't know what to do with this question now. Is the above comment the Answer? Doesn't seem like it.

Answer (score 1):

Could they be excluded?

Check your include/exclude rules.

If they are not, create a new workspace.  If they appear in the new workspace, just remove the old one.  I have seen this issue before in the past.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, but a) I'm aware of our exclude rules, which haven't changed, and don't apply to these files, and b) they came back on their own without me doing anything I'm aware of, as noted above. Still a mystery, but not one that's in my face any more, knock silicon...